# Insert ID in column with values separated by comma

Tags: mysql

I have a column that lists all the units ids from a company which are allowed to see a specific document.

Like this:

[image: List of the Unit's IDs]

And those ids are selected here ('Selecionar todas' mean 'Select All'):

[image]

The problem is when I add a new Unit, it come unselected and it will be a headache to have to enter in all of the documents that are supposed to show to all units and change it to be selected.

Is there a way to insert the new Unit's  id into the 'idsunidades' column where there are all the other units selected ?

Sorry for the bad English.

Comment: You could use one more **Flag column** for `Select All` is `true` or `false`. If it is true u can select all units otherwise select mentioned units.

Comment: @VigneshKumar that's would be a good idea ! I would go for that way but we didn't want to change the logic behind that table. Btw, thanks for the reply !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To implement a select all option you should use a flag column all_selected(true or false) or you can do it like this:

To select the rows where All units are selected should have the longest  value of idsunidades, you can select them like this

```
SELECT @maxLength:=LENGTH(idsunidades) 
ORDER BY LENGTH(idsunidades ) 
DESC LIMIT 1
```

You can use `CONCAT()` to append the new id to the old column data

To add the unit 99 to the column idsunidades to all the rows with all units you can do this

```
UPDATE table set idsunidades=CONCAT(idsunidades, ',99')
WHERE LENGTH(idsunidades) = (SELECT LENGTH(idsunidades) 
                             ORDER BY LENGTH(idsunidades ) 
                             DESC LIMIT 1)
```

Comment: That's so smart yet so simple. Never thought about that ! Thanks for the reply, you're awesome !